# Java plugin not running in Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, plugins

I tried to create and run plugin in jsp, but I cann't run it in Firefox.

How can I turn on this plugin, because I cann't find it extensions of Firefox to turn on. Java and Firefox are the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Download the jxpiinstall installation not the JDK one. The best way to install Java and run FireFox is to get the JRE running not the JDK, I found out that installing each on separate folders did the trick for me. So I have my JDK in : C:\jdk1.8.0_60 And my JRE in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60 First, you need to remove java from your pc, uninstall FF and reinstall FF then Java